# How to sign data with RSA private Key on Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, cryptography

I got this C# code but I need it to be done in Javascript. The idea is that I need to execute this bit of code when there is no internet in the browser, basically, I have to save some data in the local storage and then use them to execute this method to generate a private key.

```
private static string SignData(string ppath,string ppass)
{
    X509Certificate2 keyStore = new X509Certificate2(ppath, ppass);
    RSA privateKey = keyStore.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    byte[] iicSignature = privateKey.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pConcat), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    byte[] iic = ((HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(iicSignature);
    return BitConverter.ToString(iic).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

P.S:
I managed to extract the private key and save it to local storage.Now I need to sign some data with this key,SHA256 algorithm and pkcs1 padding.

Comment: I will think about it but savings private certificate with JavaScript on unsecure storage is a risk if you aware of that

Comment: @MaythamFahmi I am totally aware but thats the only solution on my task

Comment: Does the JavaScript code need to extract the key from a PFX/PKCS#12 file (that's what it looks like according to the code) or does the key already exist (that's what it looks like according to the title) and if the latter, which format does the key have?

Comment: @Topaco I can extract a key and save it as a string to local storage but I am not sure how to sign the data with it because on c# the RSA key object has a `.SignData()` method but after i save it to local storage the RSA key becomes a string.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @Topaco .Net framework 4.6.1

Comment: .NET Framework is very limited in its capabilities for key export, can you use C#/BouncyCastle?

Comment: @Topaco Maybe if I convince my team leader, but I have extracted a key already but im not sure if I can use it in any way. It's in this format : `<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>XXXXXXXXX</Modulus><Exponet>AQAB</Exponent><RSAKeyValue>`

Comment: This is a public key. You need a private key for signing, i.e. you have to use `ToXmlString(true)`. For this way you need a library that supports the XML format.

Comment: Alternatively you can convert the key with tools or online to a more common format like PKCS#8 or JWK. Or you can use C#/BouncyCastle which directly supports export in PKCS#8 format. This format is supported by most libraries.

Comment: @Topaco I have tried `ToXmlString(true)` but i get 'The requested operation is not supported.` also i need this specific way of converting because this key is also gonna be generated form another party with the same parameters and certificate so the 2 generated keys need to be the same in order for the receipt to be recognized.

Comment: Since @Topaco didn't comment on it maybe I'm missing something but it looks like you're computing the signature but then returning the MD5 hash of the signature. If that's true then it's impossible to verify the signature.

Comment: Why did you remove the [link to the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244738/discussion-between-shatsuki-and-topaco)? The infos, especially the options described, should be helpful in answering after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of use [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) to extract your private key from the certificate and convert it to pkcs8.

Then you will need to find a javascript library that does sign data with a private key. I suggest you use the `window.crypto` library that is supported by most browsers. It has a method called `window.crypto.subtle.sign()` which signs data using a private key you have to import with `window.crypto.subtle.importKey()` you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle) about this library.

And finally you will need a md5 library to hash the signed data. You can find that [here.](http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5.js)

It's mostly what you've talked about in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244738/discussion-between-shatsuki-and-topaco).

Comment: I will give it a look and ask you for any more help i need